# The design Layout Gives Runtime Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I'm designing a simple  layout for my android application but when i write the code below in the xml file of my activity II receive a runtime exception,I mean"Unfortunately [My Project Name] has stopped".would you please guide me through this?

thanks a lot
here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <Textview 
        android:id="@+id/txtFName"
        android:text="FirstName"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#E6CDFE"
                    />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/lblFName"
        android:hint="Please Enter Your FirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does your logcat say? Clearly explain the exception you are getting and get back.

Comment: Post the complete logcat exception trace, please

Comment: 12-12 12:24:40.953: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(86): setKernelCountSet(10051, 1) failed with errno -2
12-12 12:24:41.030: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(86): setKernelCountSet(10004, 0) failed with errno -2
12-12 12:24:41.030: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(86): setKernelCountSet(10004, 1) failed with errno -2
12-12 12:24:41.030: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(86): setKernelCountSet(10051, 0) failed with errno -2
12-12 12:24:50.291: W/ActivityManager(86): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{411cb680 com.example.fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff/.Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}

Comment: @SohaSoha if my solution is helpful to you then you can accept my answer. If there is any issues then let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtFName"
        android:text="FirstName"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#E6CDFE"
                    />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/lblFName"
        android:hint="Please Enter Your FirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This will work perfectly for you.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your care.it worked.but I can't recognize the difference !!would you please tell me which line you've revised?

Comment: Thanks. Its is easy to recognize the difference. Its mine : 'TextView'  and Its your : 'Textview'. ;)